# Built-in solution for grouping and aggregating TClientDataSet data into another data set

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tclientdataset

I have access log to my API with request time and URI. I load the data into TClientDataSet component.

| time | req |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 10:01:01 | /identify |
| 2021-05-01 10:01:02 | /identify |
| 2021-05-01 10:01:03 | /identify |
| 2021-05-01 10:02:01 | /add-bio |
| 2021-05-01 10:02:01 | /identify |

Now I want to display the requests per minute statistics in a chart. For that I have to aggregate the data into another `TClientDataSet` (let's call it `cdsRequestsPerMinute`) like this:

| minute | req | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 10:01:00 | /identify | 3 |
| 2021-05-01 10:02:00 | /add-bio | 1 |
| 2021-05-01 10:02:00 | /identify | 1 |

There is lots of info on grouping and aggregation of `TClientDataSet` records but the result is more like "window functions" produce in SQL and not the grouping returning unique records for grouping criteria.

I understand I could go record by record and add the record to the `cdsRequestsPerMinute` if not yet present or increase count otherwise. Is there a built-in solution?

**EDIT 1**

To get the minute I use this function:

```
function TruncSeconds(const AVal: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  _H, _M, _Sec, _MSec: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(AVal, _H, _M, _Sec, _MSec);
  Result := Trunc( AVal ) + EncodeTime(_H, _M, 0, 0);
end;
```

It simply removes the seconds from the TDateTime value.

Naive approach is for every request I:

```
procedure TForm1.AddRequest(const _Req: TRequestInfo);
begin
  //request list
  cdsRequests.Insert;
  cdsRequestsstart.Value := _Req.Start;
  cdsRequestsuri.Value := _Req.Uri;
  cdsRequestsduration_ms.Value := _Req.DurationMs;
  cdsRequeststhread.Value := _Req.Thread;
  cdsRequestsclient.Value := _Req.Client;
  cdsRequests.Post;

  //statistics
  if cdsReqsPerMinute.Locate(
    cdsReqsPerMinuteminute.FieldName+';'+cdsReqsPerMinuterequest.FieldName,
    VarArrayOf([TruncSeconds(_Req.Start), _Req.Uri]),
    []) then
  begin
    cdsReqsPerMinute.Edit;
    cdsReqsPerMinutecount.Value := cdsReqsPerMinutecount.Value + 1;
    cdsReqsPerMinute.Post;
  end
  else
  begin
    cdsReqsPerMinute.Insert;
    cdsReqsPerMinuteminute.Value := TruncSeconds(_Req.Start);
    cdsReqsPerMinuterequest.Value := _Req.Uri;
    cdsReqsPerMinutecount.Value := 1;
    cdsReqsPerMinute.Post;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're wanting. It's sorted by time then req. Do you want it sorted by req then time?

Comment: I want to somehow get a dataset that is aggregated based on minute. If I add aggregate fileds to the initial query I end up with as many rows as there was in the beginning. I want unique (minute, req) field pair in the result.

Comment: Show an example of what you want to see, not the query you think is not working. Maybe edit the post above to show it because it will look like crap if you put it in a message here. Honestly, what works best is to show "here is what I have and here is what I want. But I'm getting this..." Aside from that, I'm wondering how you're handling the rounding on the times. You show xx:xx:00 in the example above but you're not showing how you're getting that. Is it in the SQL query? Or in Delphi code?

Comment: Thank you @David for the interest in the question. I've appended the question with a function fro time -> minute transformation. Now regarding other questions: I have a TClientDataSet `cdsRequests` with fields 'time' and 'req' and values visible in the first table (RecordCount=5). I want to transform the same dataset or fill the new one with aggregated data like in table 2 (RecordCount3). I'll add a naive implementation of what I want to atchieve into the question. The question is if there is a better, already build-in way.

Comment: I wasn't asking for the code but rather what the output is that you want to see. You showed something that seems to be what you DON'T want. All of the info is how you're getting something you don't want, but ... what DO you want the output to look like?

Comment: @David, the desired result is described in my second table. I want a dataset with 3 records.

Comment: At the end of the day, SOMETHING has to iterate over the records, count up how many of each matching timestamp exist, and write that number to a field. Since the input record is already current at that point, the only other thing to optimize is the Locate operation. Since the input data is presumably already ordered by time, you could check to see if the minute 'bin' has changed or not and if so then create the next one, leaving it open for the next input record. You could have several minute 'bins' that will all post once the minute mark has changed. For slow data, this won't make much diff.

Comment: You've got two loops here any way you look at it: the first is the input data, which should be ordered by increasing timestamp value. The other is the minute 'bins'. Splitting them up isn't going to speed anything up. But keeping the current minute's 'bins' open and current will speed things up for high-speed data -- that is, where you've got a lot of hits per minute. Then you can ditch the Locate and just loop over the open bins looking for a name match. Select your req fields so they're unique in the first 3 chars and skip the first if it's always '/' and it'll be hard to get much faster.

Comment: Thank you, @David for the insight. Could you explain what you meen by "bins"? I currently have 2 distinct req values, may be more latter but not mutch more (up to ten).

Comment: 'bin' or 'bucket' is where you collect all of the matching items after setting the seconds in all of the times to zero. If you got one per second for a given req, there would be 60 items in a single bin for that time and req.